# SQL Query to txt

Tags: mysql

I have table which contains id and username.

How can i export each username to txt file having id as name.

For example:

1.txt having 1st username

2.txt having 2nd username

3.txt having 3rd username

And so on. Can it be done?

Comment: u should upload ur code up to now

Answer (score 0):

If you have (g)awk installed, this could be a solution:

`` mysql -D [database] -BNe "SELECT `username`, `id` FROM [table]" | awk '{ print $1 >> "/tmp/" $2 ".txt"}' ``